# MFC Main thread only focus on Dialog, need to deal with the data received from server

Tags: c++, mfc

My code will **receive xml data** from server, the data quite huge.
after finishing receiving the xml data from sever, my code want to continue to parse the xml data, however, I have no idea why the thread focus on the dialog to receive message from system to paint or do something else... NO WAY TO go back to the parsing code. 
however, if i close the dialog, it will go back the parsing code automatically?

what is the problem? please help me.....

Comment: Can we have a look at ur code..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while fetching data from internet your onpaint message of dialog is pending in message loop.Becose as you said its big data, So it hangs your application.All other messages placed in message queue.As soon as your applicationr return back from hang condition all messages that present in queque started execution.Finally dialog's WM_PAINT message is also pending which execute after hange condition finish and before reading of xmle file.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform the "receive and parse xml data" in a separate thread if you need the dialog to be responsive during that time.

Use [CreateThread()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453%28VS.85%29.aspx) to start a thread, you can check if the thread has terminated (and get the exit code of the thread) using [GetExitCodeThread()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Alternatively, you can use the MFC [CWinThread class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/48xz4yz9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to do the same thing.

Comment: [`CreateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453.aspx) is usually the wrong tool. If an application calls the CRT (i.e. pretty much any application) it should use [`_beginthreadex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx) instead.